# Grab a random number of bytes from a file with bash?

Tags: linux, bash, random, dd

I have a file of 256MB. I'd like to retrieve a random amount of data from this file and copy it to another file.

Is there a way to do this in bash or some other way?

Edit: choose a random number between 1 and 256 then copy that number of mb from one file to another.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "random"? Are you asking how to generate a random number? Or do you just mean "arbitrary"?

Comment: Is this homework? There aren't a lot of real reasons to do this...

Comment: homework?  lol - no.  I finished college in 98.

Comment: All right. It just always seems suspicious to me when there's such a specific question asking how to do something I'd probably never do.

Comment: Heh - even when I was in college I asked odd questions like this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your OS has a /dev/urandom, then picking random numbers is easy:

```
RANDNUM=`dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1 count=1 | od -t u1 | cut -f4- -d ' ' | head -1 | sed 's/ //g'`
```

Once you have a random number,

```
dd if=input_file of=output_file bs=${RANDNUM}m count=1
```

Comment: Bash has a builtin RANDOM variable

Comment: @Jürgen: Good to know. I use tcsh, which so far as I know, does not.

Answer (score 4):

This copies starting from the beginning:

```
# (random) blocks of one byte
dd of=output_file if=input_file ibs=1 count=$((($RANDOM % 256) + 1)M

# one block of (random) bytes
dd of=output_file if=input_file ibs=$((($RANDOM % 256) + 1)M count=1
```

Use the `skip=` option to start from somewhere else, if you want.

(My bad, forgot to specify the block size.)

Comment: This is copying the entire contents of the input file.

Comment: It should be pointed out that `$RANDOM` is a builtin automatic variable in Bash which contains pseudorandom numbers in the range 0-32767.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat somefile|head -c `head -c 3 /dev/random |hexdump -d|cut -f4 -d ' '|head -n1`
```